# Combining feature collections into one geometry and prep for export in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, geometry, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, feature-class, feature-collection

I am trying to create a new feature class (polygon) by combining different feature classes into one and also removing any overlap. I am a beginner in GIS & GEE .

I will share my code below:

```
// After Loading the VIIRS Nighttime Lights Dataset and FAO Level 2 Boundaries,
// I created variables containing the Somali inhabited areas of Dji, Eth, KE, & Som

var Somalia = worldCountries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Somalia'))
var Ethiopia = worldCountries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Somali'))
var Kenya = worldCountries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'North Eastern'))
var Djibouti = worldCountries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Djibouti'));
var somDji = Djibouti.filter(ee.Filter.inList('ADM2_NAME',["As Eyla", "Dikhil", "Djibouti", "Ali Sabieh"]));




// Now I will convert the Lights dataset into a list of images
var Imgs = ee.ImageCollection(Lights).toList(102);

// Then I will select the first and last images of this collection which are: 
// January 01st 2014 & June 01st, 2022. We will then store them in variables.
var gSomalia2014 = ee.Image(ee.List(Imgs).get(0));
var gSomalia2022 = ee.Image(ee.List(Imgs).get(101));
```

My end goal of this project is to create a change map of 2014-2022 of nighttime lights in the geometry I specified I want to create called 'greaterSomalia'.